# Simple spec file for creating RPM package

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a binary Java `run.jar` file, a bash script `run.sh` which executes `run.jar` via `java -jar`.

- In my environment (`~/rpmbuild/`), where do I have to put those two files? Where do I have to put the source file? (I guess I should compress the source as `.tar.gz`)

How can I write the spec file to:

- Make directory `~/bin/my-package`;
- Copy `run.jar` and `run.sh` to above directory;

That's all I want. Would you please help me a little?

Thanks for your time.

P.S: I went through this [how-to](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package). Unfortunately I'm newbie in this, I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create ~/.rpmmacros to set up RPM build environment.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS/{i{3,4,5,6}86,x86_64,noarch},SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
$ echo "%_topdir $HOME/rpmbuild" > ~/.rpmmacros
```

And put run.jar/run.sh and spec file into ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES and ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/ respectively.

**EDIT:** In a spec file:

```
(skip)

Source0: run.jar
Source1: run.sh

(skip)

%install

%{__mkdir_p} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/path/to/my-package

%{__install} -m0644 %{SOURCE0} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/path/to/my-package
%{__install} -m0644 %{SOURCE1} ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/path/to/my-package

(skip)

%files
/path/to/my-package/*
```

Comment: Thanks. But I commented out `%prep`, `%build` (to skip them). And `rpmbuild -ba ...` raised error with `.configure`... Could you please just do a test in your machine, only put an `example.sh` in your `SOURCES` and write the spec file to: make a dir `~/bin/test`, copy `example.sh` to `~/bin/`?

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm figuring it out. Commenting `# %configure` does not work. Instead I use `# configure` (no `@`)… Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't edit @Taizo Ito's answer because there are lots of changes. His answer is right, but I update to newest RPM build [guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package):

```
# skip

Source0: run.jar
Source1: run.sh

#skip

%install

rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/my-package
cp %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/my-package
cp %{SOURCE1} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/my-package

# skip

%files
%{_bindir}/my-package/*

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

# ...
```